# Could not set Session variable from class in app_code

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Web Server calls `MagicServer` to perform certain calculations. `MagicServer` return final result string after calculation completed but while in progress `MagicServer` sends message through events. The events are being handled in Web Server with `ClientEventSink`. I could receive message in  `ClientEventSink` but could not set `Session` there since it is `null`.

CS file in app_code : MagicPerformer.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.Remoting;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp;
using System.Web;
using MagicAgent;

namespace MyWeb.Magic
{
    class ClientEventSink : MessageEventSink
    {
        protected override void ClientCallback(string str)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["MagicServerMessage"] = str; // **Could not get SESSION here. Current null.**
        }

    }

    public class MagicPerformer
    {

      public string GetMagicString(int magicCount)
      {
        string magicString = string.Empty;

        IChannel preregistered = ChannelServices.GetChannel("magicSink");
        if (preregistered == null)
        {
            IDictionary props = new Hashtable();
            props["name"] = "magicSink";
            props["port"] = 0;
            props["rejectRemoteRequests"] = "false";

            BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider serverProv = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
            serverProv.TypeFilterLevel = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.TypeFilterLevel.Full; 
            BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider clientProv = new BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider();

            TcpChannel tcpCh = new TcpChannel(props, clientProv, serverProv);
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(tcpCh, false);
        }

        MagicSearcher magician = (MagicSearcher)Activator.GetObject(typeof(MagicSearcher), "tcp://192.168.1.15:8010/magicsearcher");
        if (magician == null)
            throw new Exception("SERVER_NOT_RUNNING");

        RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(ClientEventSink),"RemotingBroadcast",WellKnownObjectMode.SingleCall); 

        ClientEventSink sink = new ClientEventSink();
        ClientEventHandler clientEventHandler = new ClientEventHandler(sink.ServiceDispatchMethod);

        try
        {
            magician.ClientServiceEvent += clientEventHandler;
            magicString = magician.GetMagicStringFromServer(magicCount);
        }
        catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException se)
        {
            throw new Exception("CONNECTION_ERROR", se);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        magician = null;
        return magicString;
     }

  }

}
```

How could i set `Session` from `ClientEventSink` so that i could show progress message in webpage.

Comment: I don't see how you call the ClientCallback method. you just make the ClientEventSink object, and not call the ClientCallback.

Comment: ClientEventSink is event handler object which handles events from "MagicServer". The method call for "ClientCallback" is performed within the MagicAgent.DLL. Till now "ClientCallback" is being called with string value like "Currently calculating magic 2 out of 5." I want to set this message "Currently calculating ...." in Session.